# Show that the space of solutions of $\dot x=A(t)x$ is a linear subspace of space of differentiable functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the space of solutions of $\dot x=A(t)x$ is a linear subspace of space of differentiable functions. $A(t)$ is not necessarily invertible. I am afraid I don't know how to approach is. The notes would suggest something similar but won't regard $x(t)$. Am I even looking at $x(t)$ kind of solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember first-year linear algebra.
If $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are both solutions, then 
$$\frac d{dt}(x+y)=\dot x+\dot y=A(t)x+A(t)y=A(t)(x+y)$$ 
so $x+y$ is also a solution to the DE.
Do the same with a scalar multiple.

Comment: How can I show that the dimension of the solutions space is $n$ exactly, if $A(t)$ is continuous? I gave a lot of thought with not success. I tried differentiating but it led me nowhere.